# how to export android application in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated my Adt bundle with current version (api 18). in previous version i did the following stpes to export android app.File---> export--->android application----> project---->use existing keystore with password --->select alias & Password -----> Destination apk file.
if  i export the  android application in   new ADT ,it    would  be in key  format(FILE). am i miss something?

Comment: which format is it then??

Comment: @ASP key format(FILE)

Comment: that is the keystore u created.....

Comment: use that keystore to sign your app...and get it from the destination folder.

Comment: @ASP i already created a keystore for ma app.but that time i didnt enable proguard

Comment: now try signing the app with the keystore and export.....and also check whether u r getting any errors while exporting.

Comment: @ASP thats wheat i did before

Comment: @Asp i tracked the error and i updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

Use this description to know more about ProGuard

When you create an Android project, a proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project. 
To enable ProGuard so that it runs as part of an Ant or Eclipse build, set the proguard.config property in the `<project_root>/project.properties` file. The path can be an absolute path or a path relative to the project's root.

If you left the proguard.cfg file in its default location (the project's root directory), you can specify its location like this:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

You can also move the file to anywhere you want, and specify the absolute path to it:

```
proguard.config=/path/to/proguard.cfg
```

These will help you to get solution.

Comment: it's showing error proguard.cfg doesnot exist.or its not a regular file.